# how to position the arrow under a list item in css

Tags: css, css-position

I am new to CSS. I have a un-ordered list containing list item making it a navigation bar. Now the second list item contains a sub-list which I am displaying inside a div. Its somewhat similar to the link present in [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/). I am able to develop the div container containing the sub elements, but I am struck in displaying a down arrow on the corresponding li element when I hover it. I have also created the down-arrow using css but need to know how to position it under the li element of the parent navigation.

Please let me know how to position the arrow under the li so that it works on all browsers and with all dimensions.

Added the jsfiddle link:[fiddle link`<div></div`](http://jsfiddle.net/7bUxw/)

Comment: It will be Great if you add some of your code. It is hard to understand something when you doesnt see anything. If you add position:relative to the <li> then you can to operate by rules : top and left

Comment: shall I share the jsfiddle link to you?

Comment: yes you can help by doing that

Comment: Shared the jsfiddle net link